# Trying to filter a nested tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter, tuples

I'm trying to sort a list of tuples into a list containing only tuple with equal number of even and odd integers that aren't in sequential order. Here's the code so far (sorry if it's messy I just started to learn python)

```
from itertools import combinations as comb
import itertools
from typing import Any, Tuple, Union

# combinations

list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
          11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
          21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
          31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
          50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
          60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69]

list_2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
          11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
          21,22,23,24,25,26]


pick_5 = list(comb(list_1,5))

pick_1 = list(comb(list_2,1))

combos = list(itertools.product(pick_5,pick_1))

print("Number of unsorted combos:", len(combos))

#testing tuples

print("run test:")

print(combos[0])
print(combos[1])

print(combos[0][0][0])
print(combos[0][0][1])
print(combos[0][0][2])
print(combos[0][0][3])
print(combos[0][0][4])
print(combos[0][1][0])

#filters

combos =[]

even_odd =[
    {(t[0][0][0], t[0][0][1], t[0][0][2], t[0][0][3], t[0][0][4]), (t[0][1][0])}
    for t in combos
    if (t[0][0][0] % 2 == 0 and t[0][0][1] % 2 == 0 and t[0][0][2] % 2 == 0 and t[0][0][3] % 2 != 0 and t[0][0][4] % 2 != 0) and (t[0][1][0] % 2 != 0)
]

sequence = [
    {(t[0][0][0], t[0][0][1], t[0][0][2], t[0][0][3], t[0][0][4]), (t[0][1][0])}
    for t in combos
    if (t[0][0][0] and t[0][0][1] == t[0][0][0] + 1 and t[0][0][2] == t[0][0][0] + 2 and t[0][0][3] == t[0][0][0] + 3 and t[0][0][4] == t[0][0][0] + 4)  and (t[0][1][0] == t[0][0][0] + 5)
]

evenodd_dict = {e[0] ** 2 + e[1] ** 2 + e[2] ** 2 + e[3] ** 2 + e[4] ** 2 + e[5] ** 2 : e for e in even_odd}

sequence_dict = {s[0] ** 2 + s[1] ** 2 + s[2] ** 2 + s[3] ** 2 + s[4] ** 2 + s[5] ** 2 : s for s in sequence}

#final sort

final_dict = {}
final_dict.update(evenodd_dict)

print(final_dict)
print("done")
print ("Number of combos =", len(final_dict))
```

And this is the output I get:

```
    Number of unsorted combos: 141999312
run test:
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1,))
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (2,))
1
2
3
4
5
1
{}
done
Number of combos = 0
```

Need help figuring out why it's not returning any results, i assume it's in the filter definitions

Appreciate the help thank you!

Comment: One mistake is in `even_odd` and `sequence` where you want to create the tuple with one element. This is just an int: `(1)`, this is a tuple with one element: `(1,)`

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining `combos` as an empty list before you create the `even_odd` list.

```
combos =[]

even_odd =[
    {(t[0][0][0], t[0][0][1], t[0][0][2], t[0][0][3], t[0][0][4]), (t[0][1][0])}
    for t in combos
    if (t[0][0][0] % 2 == 0 and t[0][0][1] % 2 == 0 and t[0][0][2] % 2 == 0 and t[0][0][3] % 2 != 0 and t[0][0][4] % 2 != 0) and (t[0][1][0] % 2 != 0)
]
```

This means that `for t in combos` will loop zero times, so `even_odd` will also be empty.

Comment: Ah ok that’s pretty dumb on my end haha. Removing that line gives me a ‘int’ is not subscriptable error. Thoughts?